# Would a water manipulating Devil Fruit user be able to swim?

Tags: one-piece

If all Devil Fruit users in *One Piece* anime are not capable of swimming, what about a Devil Fruit user whose ability is to control water? Can such a person able to swim or evade the Devil Fruit's curse?

Comment: There's no such fruit, as far as I know. And I believe that's intentional.

Comment: According to explanation in anime , all devil fruit users unable to swim but That is possible to across the water though. example ( Aokiji cycling via sea;  turn out water as ice , Brook walking on water since his body is too light )

Comment: wasn't there one water water fruit user in movie karakuri island or something. she transforms into water an moves through pipes to attack nami.

Comment: What I think, is that if they were drenched in water, it wouldn't matter, but if they fell into the ocean, then they would become solid and sink.

Comment: It was stated that a water devil fruit doesn't exist as it would defeat the whole purpose of being weak to water.

Answer (score 12):

Most of this answer is speculation as there is currently no answer to this question.

I think that the possibility of the "Mizu Mizu no Mi" existing somewhere in the One Piece universe is highly possible, since we have already seen multiple states of water being Devil Fruits:

- [Moku Moku no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Moku_Moku_no_Mi) (Smoke - Gas state)*
- [Hie Hie no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hie_Hie_no_Mi) (Ice - Solid state)
- [Yuki Yuki no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yuki_Yuki_no_Mi) (Snow - Solid state)

<sup>* I know this one is disputable</sup>

The only problem with the "Mizu Mizu no Mi" is that it will create a paradox.
Since Devil Fruit users are weak to water, if a Devil Fruit user transforms into water, he would be rendered powerless and transform back to his normal form.

But all in all, I don't think the person using this Devil Fruit will be able to circumvent the "curse" Devil Fruit users get from eating them.

Comment: Devil fruit users are weak against the sea. Regular water does not affect them. See Luffy's battle with Crocodile

Comment: I believe that moving water has no effect on devil fruit users (showers, waterfalls, waves, etc.), but ocean water does. More than likely because salt is seen as a tool against the devil and demons, hence why they can't swim, but fresh water does not have the same attribute.

Comment: Smoke isn't water in gas state.

Comment: A significant component of smoke is water vapor. (The rest is carbon dioxide and particulates.)

Answer (score 5):

The Devil Fruit Users are weak to the sea energy (think seastone), because the sea hates them. If a "Mizu Mizu no Mi" exists, then it would most likely be fresh water ability. This would allow them to use water, without being weakened.

Comment: My thought entirely. As long as they only touch fresh water, devils fruit users seem to be unaffected. Such is the example of luffy drowning in Arlong's pool (connected to the sea) but unaffected by Hancock's bath. Therefore a 水水の実 would be purely fresh water.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the Devil Fruit users only lose their powers through SEA water. drinking water, fresh water and any other type of water would have no effect. So it would be possible to have the ability and swim, if you are not in Sea water. This was displayed in the Crocodile ARC. Luffy dowses himself with regular water to fight Crocodile for the fact that the Sand gets clumpy and is not able to disperse.

Comment: This answer is contradicted by [this SBS](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_41#Chapter_398.2C_Page_206) in which it states, *"The "sea" here can refer to anything from rivers, pools and baths to any kind of standing water."*

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR **YES, they can swim**

Assuming the fruit eater cannot control the sea water (which otherwise would clearly goes against all the plot), he'd have to use tricks to enable him swimming.

> [Devil Fruit](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit) users are susceptible to all types of water, not just seawater

I'll assume this Devil Fruit will not be susceptible to fresh water. This can be possible since the wiki always states the word "sea" as the weakness. It has nothing to do with water. For example, it's "seastone", not "waterstone". We can say susceptibility of fresh water is a side effect which can be neutralized with the power of the fruit.

> Logia Devil Fruits allow a person to **create**, control, and transform
>   into a natural element or force of nature, depending on the fruit.

Let us also assume the fruit is [Logia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Logia) type. If the fruit has the ability to create water, the fruit user could surround themself with newly created fresh water which is not their own body. This way, there will be no direct interaction with the sea water and the Devil Fruit user.

With these assumptions, yes, a fruit user with such power will have the ability to swim in salty water.

Check [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/23344/why-can-devil-fruit-users-use-their-abilities-while-wet/23369#23369) answer for further details.

Comment: It would be impossible for fruit users to swim due to the curse. Also your assumptions does not prove your claim. If they would turn into water, then they would indeed be fine, because moving water has no effect, but if they would create water, it would be no different from any other still water. If a water fruit user would create water and if any fruit user would be submerged by it, they would lose their energy as long as it isn't moving water.

Comment: @PeterRaeves I think you missed the 2nd assumption. If the devil power `neutralizes` the effect of fresh(still) waters weakening effect then the user can surround the body with fresh water and can submerge. With proper water creation some force will also be produced which can enable the user to move underneath the ocean.

Comment: But the second assumption is incorrect. The wiki states that the type of water is not important. Both fresh water and sea water are harmful as long as it is still and not moving. That's why luffy can run around with sea water on him, and that's why pirates can shower, but not bath.

Comment: @Peter Raeves Correct. But according to wiki there could be no human with 2 devil powers before marineford. Black beards fruit which can neutralize one of the standard effect of a devil fruit. My assumption was like that. It's not an impossible assumption thats why the teory may work.

Comment: Well only Blackbeard can neutralize the effects of a Devil Fruit, because it is part of his powers, but he cannot neutralize the effects of the sea. If Blackbeard falls into the ocean he would drown just as the others (I assume).

Comment: Exactly. His devil fruit can make him able to control 2 devil fruit powers which is normally impossible. The water-water fruit may have a distinct ability which **may** neutralize the effect of fresh water where other devil fruit powers can't. You got the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

No. The second he touched water or became wet, he would lose the ability to control it, allowing him to drown and die. If he controlled water from a distance without touching it, then he could retain his devil fruit powers.

Comment: there was a mizu mizu no mi user in movie 3 or 4(don't rem properly) and she couldn't control the water. she used to moves through the pipes by turning into water. and nami caught her inside a glass jar to stop her.

Comment: @Sp0T that wasn't mizu mizu that was either the toro toro no mi(movie2) or the ame ame no mi(movie 4) :P

Comment: well i checked and indeed it is the toro toro no mi. ;) but isn't water also is a liquid. so she couldn't control any liquid.