# Could there be a Devil Fruit that makes you an outstanding swimmer?

Tags: one-piece

In One Piece, is there a Devil Fruit that makes you a great swimmer? It seems impossible since eating a Devil Fruit makes you unable to swim. Does the series ever address this?

Comment: If this question might be opinion based, the popular similar question definitely is: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5041/would-a-water-manipulating-devil-fruit-user-be-able-to-swim?rq=1  I do believe my answer removes any opinion though.

Comment: Do you mean a swimmer as one who *exclusively* swims in water?

Answer (score 16):

There is actually a canon answer to this.  The Sui-Sui No Mi (official english name is Swim-Swim fruit) is a Paramecia Fruit eaten by Senior Pink.

As the ocean is inaccessible to Devil Fruit users, the Swim-Swim Fruit makes you an excellent swimmer... through anything else including solid material (except seastone).

Unless Oda decides to create one, no devil fruit will exist which is a loophole to allow the user to swim through water.

Comment: I think we should also mention Brooke because, thanks to his DF, he became a skeleton and is now able to RUN on water. Which is basically beating the system. :P

Comment: @Gravinco There are several DF that allow you to cross water or fly over it but these aren't loopholes or swimmers.  They are never submerged.

Comment: I know, but I thought it was worth mentioning :)